# Dual network interface control with systemd

Tags: debian, networking, networkmanager, systemd-networkd

On a debian machine, I have two network interfaces: eth1 and eth2.

Eth1 is static and eth2 is using dhcp. How to make so that when the eth1 interface is active, the eth2 interface is down and vice versa? Basically I want the two interfaces never to be active at the same time.
I've started to make a script with ifdown ifup in the crontab but obviously we should be able to do it with systemd.

Do you have any idea how to make this easy?

Comment: I've never had to do it, so I can't explain it. Hopefully someone else will come along and help you more than I can. However, I *think* what you're looking for isn't a script but is something called 'netplan'. I'd do some searches with that keyword and see where it takes you. Again, I can't help - but I saw you had no answers so I figured I'd throw 'netplan' out there as that seems to be how they're doing this now.

Comment: Why would you want to disable one?  I had a similar use-case where I brought my laptop to work with embedded devices over `eno1`, but when I go back to my desk I switched to dhcp on `wlo1`. At first I had to disable `wlo1` each time I wanted to be on the test network, but later I figured out that I could just set up routes in a way that both connections could exist at the same time.  That meant I could have internet access while on the test network.  I could only see a case where military security policy prevent you from having both open at a time. Then routes wouldn't be a solution.

Comment: The two connections actually work at the same time but in my case of use it is absolutely necessary to separate the two networks.